# Why did the sun appear so rapidly after the climactic battle?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

At the end of *Wonder Woman*, Diana uses a thunderbolt to attack Ares at night time.

[image]

But shortly after his death the sun suddenly appears.

[image]

**How did the sun appear so quickly?**

Comment: Could it be the Dawn? Or for dramatic effect?

Comment: https://youtu.be/yn5oqtmzGMk?t=20s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official novelisation, it was the dawn.

> *Booooooosh! Ares’s final barrage of lightning hit them; they glowed
> blue and she grimaced against the searing pain. She held the pose,
> held it, and held it until, like the release of a coiled spring, the
> full force of the energy, more powerful than all the bombs ever made,
> shot back into Ares. His scream was like that of ten thousand men.
> Then he burst apart in a blaze of light that shook the world, and
> cratered the ground below.*
>
> *The God of War was no more.*
>
> ---
>
> ***Dawn.***
>
> *The rain washed the blackened smoke from the sky, and rosy colors of
> sunrise washed the world. Soldiers were rousing as if awakening from a
> nightmare—the better side of man was returning. They pulled off their
> gas masks like players in a Greek tragedy. Diana did not see Dr. Maru
> among them.*
>
> *Charlie, Sammy, and the Chief stood together, still alive; the Germans
> were leaving them alone. Then they began shaking hands. Helping one
> another. Leaving the war behind.*
>
> *A last flake of ash swirled around the Daughter of Zeus and Hippolyta.
> **She lifted her head to the breaking sun.** And in the surround of
> silence, she heard a greater silence.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Wonder Woman: The Official Movie Novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33560553-wonder-woman)</sup></sub>